# Enable VSTO Ribbon Tab

Tags: ms-word, vsto, ribbon

I've added some custom tabs to my ribbon in ribbon.xml. I have callbacks for the getVisible attribute that dynamically set the visibility of the tabs.

My problem is that when I go to Options--Customize Ribbon and uncheck my tabs, when I close Word and re-open my tabs don't re-appear even though the getVisible callback is invoked and returns true.

I've tried recording a macro when checking/unchecking the tabs, but nothing appears in my new macro. Anyone know how to force the tabs to be re-enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. This setting is stored in XML in %appdata%\local\microsoft\office\Word.officeUI and if I remove the element for my custom tab, on restarting word my tabs are visible again.